# Find a subspace $U$ of $\mathbb{R^3}$ s.t. $T(U)\subseteq U$ and s.t. $T_{|U}$ on $U$ is diagonalizable in $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, vector-spaces, diagonalization

I got stuck in this point of this exercise, do you have ideas about? Thank you.

Let $T:\mathbb{R^3}\to \mathbb{R^3}$ be an operator represented (canonical basis) by the matrix $A$ = $
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 3 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$

Find a subspace $U$ of $\mathbb{R^3}$, $dim(U)=2$, s.t. $T(U)\subseteq U$ and s.t. $T_{|U}$ on $U$, the restriction of $T$ on $U$, is diagonalizable in $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, eigenvalues:

$$|xI-A|=\begin{vmatrix}x&-1&\frac12\\
0&\,\,\;x&0\\
0&-2&x-3\end{vmatrix}=x^2(x-3)$$

Well, you have two **different** eigenvalues for your operator, and we know that *any*= operator on an $\;n\,-$ dimensional vector space with $\;n\;$ *different* eigenvalues is diagonalizable, so...what do you think your $\;U\;$ is going to be?

Comment: Got it, I'm feeling a bit stupid now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Since $(1,0,0)$ is an eigenvector of $A$ (with eigenvalue $0$), and $(-1,0,6)$ is an eigenvector of $A$ (with eigenvalue $3$)…